# How to interpret a Optimal or Infeasible Solution with 0 Branches?

Tags: c#, constraint-programming, or-tools

Getting something like

```
result:              infeasible
number of branches:  0
number of conflicts: 0
walltime:            5 ms
```

tells me, that at least one of my constraints is hurt initially and thereby there is no way for the solver finding a solution, right?

But there have been simulations showing

```
result:              optimal
number of branches:  0
number of conflicts: 0
wallime:             17ms
```

what actually makes me happy, but I don't how to handle those information. It would be great to get further insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved or proven infeasible during presolve or at the root node of the search.